# Laravel sets wrong public path with a index.php file is requested in a subdirectory

Tags: laravel, redirect, path, public

In Laravel 4.2 using Apache 2.4, if I access an *index.php* different from *index.php* in the site root then the public path is set wrong. For instance, the html document returned by `/site/index.php` is right, but all its routes to assets are relative to `/site`. For instance,

File system path: **/var/www/htdocs/imgs/logo.png**

Right url: **/imgs/logo.png**

Real path: **/site/imgs/logo.png**

This issue was discovered because the old site had you index file in `/site/index.php` and was indexed by the search engines. Then when the site is shown in the search results, it shows a link to `site/index.php` with all the assets paths broken.

The paths to assets are set with Laravel's function as `HTML::style` or `assets`

How do I redirect all the *index.php* files inside a subpath to *index.php* in the root file, except this last?

Answer (score 0):

The default *.htaccess* of Laravel 4.2 is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then I add a new *Rewrite Rule* before `#Handle Front Controller`

```
# Redirect to index.php if other index.php distict to the index.php is requested.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((.+)/)+index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301]
```

So, I redirect (permanently) to the site root to any *index.php* in a subdirectory.